# Bash process substitution used as an option value

Tags: bash, docker-compose, process-substitution

I'm trying to run

```sh
docker-compose --env-file <(cat file1.env <(echo -e "\n\n") file2.env) config
```

`docker-compose` expects `--env-file` to be a file. I need to use (concatenate) two files.

Running `docker-compose --env-file file_any.env config` works well.

Running `cat file1.env <(echo -e "\n\n") file2.env` separately outputs valid result.

But it somehow doesn't work with `docker-compose`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: No, `docker-compose` doesn't issue any errors in cases there's no file or it is empty, only can judge on the output not having variables defined in .env files.

Comment: Creating a temporary file in /tmp or /dev/shm (if available) is not an option?

Comment: @Cyrus, it is, but not the desired one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an additional process substitution. The outer process substitution captures the standard output of *all* the commands it wraps, so you aren't limited to a single `cat` command.

```
docker-compose --env-file <( cat file1.env; printf '\n\n'; cat file2.env) config
```

Unfortunately, `docker-compose` requires the argument to `--env-file` be a real file. The value of the argument is passed directly to [`Environment.from_env_file`](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/d412a1e47fcbf58674a54247f021a2d63627018d/compose/config/environment.py#L54), which makes an explicit check via [`env_vars_from_file`](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/d412a1e47fcbf58674a54247f021a2d63627018d/compose/config/environment.py#L33):

```
def env_vars_from_file(filename, interpolate=True):
    """
    Read in a line delimited file of environment variables.
    """
    if not os.path.exists(filename):
        raise EnvFileNotFound("Couldn't find env file: {}".format(filename))
    elif not os.path.isfile(filename):
        raise EnvFileNotFound("{} is not a file.".format(filename))
    ...
```

Comment: Doesn't work, neither `--env-file <(cat file.env)` does

Comment: If `--env-file <(cat file.env)` doesn't work, then `docker-compose` expects a seekable file handle and you can't use process substitution, period.

Comment: @disfated sure script runs in bash?

Comment: @alecxs, pretty sure. @chepner is probably right since `docker-compose` is only a wrapper and passes its options down to `docker` so it can further spawn containers. It makes sense that it doesn't like what process substitution produces, what I suppose to be some kind of ephemeral file descriptor.

Comment: @Cyrus, it didn't, but apparently my problem is not about bash

Comment: I've updated the answer with evidence that a process substitution *cannot* work. This appears to be a restriction inherited from https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/, which does the actual parsing. I didn't dig into `dotenv` enough to see if that's a necessary restriction, or if it actually could read from a `/dev/fd` file (it may be restricting itself too much).